# Actionscript equivalent to PHP's __get() and __set()

Tags: php, class, actionscript, getter-setter

Is there an Actionscript equivalent to PHP's `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods? I want to be able to override the behavior of getting/setting member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

Extending the [Proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html) class allows you to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing, unfortunately.

All you can do is check for the existence of a specific property, by using either

```
myObject.hasOwnProperty (name)
```

on simple Objects or some variant of [describeType()](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) for Class instances, for example

```
describeType(myObject).accessor
```

to get an XMLList of all accessor methods or

```
describeType(myObject).variable
```

to get an XMLList of all variables.

describeType(), however, is quite expensive in terms of performance, so it pays to have some sort of type hash map to store the lists for each type and do lookups for types that have already been described once.

You could also use try/catch blocks around the parts where undefined properties might be accessed, but this also "eats" away a lot of performance, if many errors are thrown.

Comment: How is this equivalent to `__get()` and `__set()`? In PHP these act as a "catch all" for member variables, so if a member variable is not defined as a consumer tries to access it then `__get()` or `__set()` are invoked.

Comment: My bad.  I should have checked that more carefully...  I edited my answer accordingly.